# Third party app can't see data from oracle for any time after updating

Tags: oracle

I have oracle table, that updating by scheduled job:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table MY_TABLE';
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN RAISE;
        END IF;  
    END;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (id NUMBER(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, AFFECTED_ITEM VARCHAR2(255), TITLE VARCHAR(700))';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (AFFECTED_ITEM, TITLE)
    SELECT DISTINCT affected_item, title from MY_EXTERNAL_TABLE@mydblink
    ';
END;
```

I can see data from this table by SQL Developer but my python app can't see this for any hours with the sam query. It's return the empty list

Comment: As an aside, why are you dropping and recreating the table?  If you really need to empty it, just TRUNCATE.  Much faster, much  cleaner, uses far lest resources.

Comment: Thank you! I will use this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `COMMIT;` the transaction after insert for other sessions to see it. Only your session can see the uncommitted data.